# Read image file from same package

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource

I want to read a bunch of image files from my current package because I want to get access to the files when my package which includes my image files is exported to others' computer.

I just want to make sure my program can read the images no matter if the package is in my computer.

I tried

```
  File file = new File("images.jpg"); // It is wrong because the path is wrong.
  // I want to assign the image as BuffuredImage      
  BufferedImage dealerCardImage1 = ImageIO.read(file);
```

I was wondering how the path of the files should be. What should I do?

Comment: Make sure your build process is actually putting the image resource in the same package as your class in the classpath.

Comment: Please show us the content of your Jar file as an edit to your question as this will help us to better understand exactly what you're working with and what you might be doing wrong. You can do this as per [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html).

Comment: I edited my question and made it more clear.

Comment: It's clear that you're now dealing with files when you should have stuck with resources.

Answer (score 1):

put your image file inside the package of current class file and try this:

```
BufferedImage dealerCardImage1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images.jpg"));
```

Note that, `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)` returns an InputStream that points to a path that starts from current package.

For example if you have a class file named `HelloWorld` inside package `com.example`, then `HelloWorld.class.getResourceAsStream("images.jpg")` returns an `InputStream` to image with this path: `com/example/images.jpg`

Comment: +1 for being 'the voice of reason amongst the screaming insanity'..

Answer (score 0):

if you read from file use

```
    Image image = new Image();

            image = ImageIO.read(file);

            // Read from an input stream
            InputStream is = getClass()
.getResourceAsStream("/com/statement/SamplePDFStatementFile.txt");
            image = ImageIO.read(is);

//if you read from url

// Read from a URL
    URL url = new URL("http://hostname.com/image.gif");
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ImageIO.read(file); will return null if no registered ImageReader is not found.
```

Please check whether you have registered any ImageReader or not.

I think this code snippet could help you

```
File file = new File("images.jpg"); // Assuming images.jpg in my working directory  
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis); //reading the image file
```

You just need to wrap the file into an FileInputStream and then pass it to read()

Comment: It's a jpg -- why would there not be an image reader for it? And why suggest he read the image as a File when it is in fact a resource?

Comment: OP mentioned about NPE - so i am trying to say the causes that might lead to it. OP also want to read a FILE to BI , so i just thought of having other simpler alternatives rather using streams.